# Can't update WooCommerce payment method title

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, post-meta

Trying to update the WooCommerce payment method as part of an AJAX call. I'm currently running this line;

```
function ajax_payUsingVCAccount(){
    update_post_meta( esc_attr( $_POST['order_id'] ), 'payment_method_title', 'commission' );
    die();
}
```

But the payment title doesn't update the `POST` variable does contain the correct `order_id`.

When I dump out the payment title afterwards it's just an empty string.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Updated

Comment: That is not enough… Please remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers"*.